# How can I make one line of a bash script into multiple lines?

Tags: bash

Im tying to make some of my bash scripts a bit easier on the eyes. Lets says I have this script and its working fine.

```
if [ "$PASSWDCHECK" = "<title>401 Authorization Required</title>" ]
then echo "The Subsubscription password is wrong" ; exit
else mkdir /home/"$USERNAME"/src && mkdir /opt/logstash && mkdir /etc/snort && mkdir /etc/snort/rules/
fi
```

I would like to make it more like this, but it fails to execute. What am I missing?

```
if [ "$PASSWDCHECK" = "<title>401 Authorization Required</title>" ]
then echo "The Subsubscription password is wrong" ; exit
else mkdir /home/"$USERNAME"/src \ &&
    mkdir /opt/logstash \ &&
    mkdir /etc/snort \ &&
    mkdir /etc/snort/rules/ \ &&
fi
```

Comment: If the backslash stands for line continuation, I would put it behind the && operator in each line.

Comment: And the last \ && is too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `\` at the end of each line, not before the `&&`. Make sure there is no whitespace after the `\`.

Comment: Actually, the backslash is unnecessary if the line ends with the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the `&&` is the last non-whitespace token on the line, the command will automatically continue onto the next line.

```
if [ "$PASSWDCHECK" = "<title>401 Authorization Required</title>" ]
then echo "The Subsubscription password is wrong" ; exit
else mkdir /home/"$USERNAME"/src &&
     mkdir /opt/logstash &&
     mkdir /etc/snort &&
     mkdir /etc/snort/rules/
fi
```

A `&&` list joins two commands, so the parser knows that a newline before the second command should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$PASSWDCHECK" = "<title>401 Authorization Required</title>" ]
then echo "The Subsubscription password is wrong" ; exit
else 
  mkdir /home/"$USERNAME"/src && \
  mkdir /opt/logstash && \
  mkdir /etc/snort && \
  mkdir /etc/snort/rules/
fi
```

Comment: I should not edit on an iPad with autocorrection on.